# Active Admin - How to add custom script before </body> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to do some analytics on my active admin enabled rails application. For that, I need to paste some `<script>` and `<noscript>` code just before the `</body>` tag in my layout file. Unfortunately, I am not able to do that as the `application.html` layout file seems ineffective since ActiveAdmin renders its own layout files.

Is there a hook/place where I can insert the custom html code ?

Comment: You can clone the git repository and bundle it from your source, is that a good enough solution for you? I'll write you a walkthrough on how doing it if so.

Comment: @Guy well, if thats what it takes, yes please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, first thing you'll have to clone the repository into your rails app, usually you'd put it in the vendor directory but rails throws this annoying warning that it will deprecate the use of the vendor directory style dir, it doesn't matter much if you're going to production with a 3.* version, so just do this into either vendor or lib directory in your rails app.

`git clone git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git`

Now change your `Gemfile` and have the gem loaded from the directory you set

`gem 'activeadmin', :path => 'lib/activeadmin'`

Now you have your *own* version of activeadmin, so whatever you need to edit you can do it directly from that dir, including changing the default layout that it is bundled with.

Few words of advise:

Although this method allows you to far more customize active admin you are fully aware that to update it to a newer version would need you to do some `git pull`ing and merging if necessary.

I used this method with jquery-ui-rails plugin and with another gem, it works splendid and moreover you can contribute to the gem back if you add the hook you wanted to the gem itself.
Good luck!

---- Edit ----

As you pointed out in a comment activeadmin doesn't work exactly how you would expect but no worries it's still an easy fix.
Under the hood activeadmin uses something called `arbre` which is created and maintained by the same developer.

`https://github.com/gregbell/arbre`, it's just a `DOM` library for ruby.

So what you have to do is this:

Head over to this file inside the activeadmin dir you just cloned `lib/active_admin/views/footer.rb`

this is the footer of the activeadmin application, as you can see inside the `build` method you can insert inside something such as `add_scripts` method and below add

```
def add_scripts
  script :src => 'http://yoursource.com'
end
```

I am not fully sure how the `arbre` syntax flows but it shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for the idea. i checked into active admin source for the layout file under app/views/layout. i see only a file called active_admin.html.arb and it has only one line in it. No idea how to insert my script over there !

Comment: Further expanded my answer :-)

Comment: Although I did not directly use your answer for the specific question I asked, it was helpful for customizing a lot other things. Accepting it now. Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Yes, this would work but forking active admin should be a last resort.

Comment: tfishbach's answer is the right one; this is way overkill to make a minor customization.

Answer (score 6):

*Tested with ActiveAdmin 0.6.0 and Rails 4.0.5.*

You can also override the [arbre](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre) view used by active admin to render the footer. In your `active_admin` initializer add:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
require 'admin/analytics_footer'

ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    config.view_factory.footer = Admin::AnalyticsFooter
  end
end
```

And define the view:

```
# lib/admin/analytics_footer.rb
module Admin
  class AnalyticsFooter < ActiveAdmin::Views::Footer
    def build
      super
      render('layouts/analytics')
    end
   end
 end
```

And place your ga tracking code in `app/views/layouts/_analytics.html.erb`. After a server restart the snippet should appear inside the footer at the end of the page.

Comment: @bnussey Though I haven't tried, I'd expect it to work with turbolinks just as well as any other way of rendering an analytics snippet. Turbolinks more or less replaces the body of the document no matter how that content is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I found it on the activeadmin site (https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html).

```
# app/admin/calendar.rb
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Calendar" do
  index do
    render partial: 'calendar'
  end
end

# app/views/admin/calendar/_calendar.html.erb
<h1>Hello</h1>
<script>
</script>
```